# windows file somehow has two versions user and Administrator

Tags: windows

I recently *resolved* a problem related to Windows 7 *Enterprise* and Windows 8 *Pro* somehow keeping two versions of a configuration file under 'Program Files'.  I found editing a config file as my **user** account had no effect on how the app launched.  But when I edited as **Administrator** I saw the file was different and the app was using that version of the config file.  Now if I view the file from either the user account or Administrator I still see two versions of the file at the apparent same path.

- how did I get into this *mode*?
- how can I get the application out of this *mode*?

### App specific details

The specific problem I had was that when I edited this NetBeans configuration file at

> C:\Program Files\Netbeans 7.3.1\etc\netbeans.conf

to point to a new JDK home (see [related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958342/68037)) it had no effect.  By apparent serendipity I thought to edit the file as Administrator and that worked.

As mentioned above when I view the file from my user account vs Administrator I see two versions of this file at the same location.  What is going on?

**UPDATE:**

I believe I found part of the answer (see https://superuser.com/a/68006/47313). But if anyone has more insight into when this happens I'd appreciate it.

Apparently instead of me as a user being told I don't have rights to update a file under *Program Files*, I now am able to write the file and it ends up in %LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore... .  I have no idea when this behavior changed (i.e. instead of being told don't have admin rights it just writes to this shadow area).

Comment: VirtualStore is a feature of the UAC to redirect calls when you don't have the permissions to write to folders like C:\Program Files. In all NT versions only admins are able to write to C:\Program Files, but you never saw this in XP, because setup made you an admin. http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/2007.06.uac%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 so then it is just a default behavior of Windows 7 now.  I understand your point of XP, but it seems like early on Windows 7 made did this also and only after some amount of Microsoft patches did it change.  That has great detail, thanks!

Comment: this feature was added in the "bad" Vista.